# "No default constructor found" using Spring MVC with Yahoo Finance API

Tags: java, spring, maven, yahoo-finance

This will be probably a stupid question but I can't figured out a possible solution by myself. 
Basically I'm trying to create a simple Java web application using Spring MVC and Yahoo Finance API.
My goal was to create a simple form where I will be able to insert the symbol of a specific stock (example: INTC (intel corporation)) and get its "dividend", "price", "quote", etc.

My addStock.jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="stock">
    <label>Symbol:</label>
    <form:input path="symbol" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

Part of AddStock.java:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params="new")
public String createForm(Model model) {
    Stock stock = new Stock();
    model.addAttribute("stock", stock);
    return "addStock";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(Stock stock, BindingResult result, Model model) throws IOException {
    String name = "";
    BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("0.00");
    BigDecimal change = new BigDecimal("0.00");
    BigDecimal peg = new BigDecimal("0.00");
    BigDecimal dividend = new BigDecimal("0.00");
    BigDecimal bookValuePerShare = new BigDecimal("0.00");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        yahooFinService.addStock(stock);
        if (YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).getQuote().getPrice() != null) {
            symbol = stock.getSymbol();
            name = YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).getName();
            price = YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).getQuote().getPrice();
            change = YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
            peg = YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).getStats().getPeg();
            dividend = YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).getDividend().getAnnualYieldPercent();
            bookValuePerShare = YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).getStats().getBookValuePerShare();
        }
        model.addAttribute("symbol", symbol);
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("price", price);
        model.addAttribute("change", change);
        model.addAttribute("peg", peg);
        model.addAttribute("dividend", dividend);
        model.addAttribute("bookValuePerShare", bookValuePerShare);

        YahooFinance.get(stock.getSymbol()).print();
    }
    return "result";
}
```

My "problem" come when I create the empty constructor "Stock".
The Yahoo Finance doesn't provide an empty constructor but just:

```
public Stock(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
```

What should I do?? Of course everything is working properly when I create a new bean, copying whole code from the API, adding the empty constructor and importing (code that I have provided) but I don't think it is the correct way to use an API and even if it is "legal".
I thought about to create a new java class which will extend the classes from Yahoo Finance API but it doesn't permit to add an empty constructor either.

I'm aware my problem is more about "java knowledge" but if someone could help me would be great. I hope I have explained properly my problem. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of why it's a good idea to decouple your data transfer objects (DTOs), which you use for your external API, from your backend data model. Instead of trying to push the Yahoo `Stock` class all the way to your UI, create a new `AddStockForm` that has just the properties needed for the interaction here.

What if you later wanted to switch from Yahoo to Google Finance? If your UI is expressed in terms of a specific internal API, you're in for a lot of extra work. If instead you decouple the frontend and backend, you can make changes independently as suitable.